# How to generate SHA1, SHA256, MD5 for default debug key using keytool in Mac, Windows and Linux?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, keytool

Gone through [Official Documentation: Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

But still, either terminal was not able to find keytool or command doesn't work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following will give you SHA1, SHA256, MD5 for default debug key. 
And it can be used for developing and debugging with google play services.

**Linux & Mac command**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**Windows**

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```

Replace  with your windows account name example:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\Users\Aakash\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
```

If asked password, type: **android**

Answer (score 0):

Follow:
The follow the article for more
https://codewithandrea.com/articles/keytool-command-not-found-how-to-fix-windows-macos/

Answer (score 0):

```
 keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\USERNAME>\.android\debug.keystore
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.