# Why is the "CONTINUE" button not showing in play store when installed app using dynamic link?

Tags: android, firebase, in-app-update

If the application is not installed on the phone and Dynamic link is clicked, it is redirected to `PlayStore`. Here, after installing the Application, the `OPEN` button appears, while the `CONTINUE` button should appear. When I press the `OPEN` button, the dynamic link becomes invalid and the dynamic link does not work when the application is first opened. Why is the `CONTINUE` button not showing?

Answer (score -2):

Your SHA-256 and SHA-1 key in your **firebase> project settings> SHA certificate fingerprints** and **Play console > Release > App Integrity > App signing key certificate** should match.

Just copy the SHA-256 from Play Console and paste it into your Firebase Project.

ps: You should also add the SHA-256 and SHA-1 keys [generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152175/how-to-generate-sha1-sha256-md5-for-default-debug-key-using-keytool-in-mac-wi) locally in your machine into firebase(you can add multiple keys in your FB project)